# Strange HTML <script async> behavior in Chrome Canary (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, asynchronous, behavior

Take the following example *index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="heading"> h1 </h1>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*1.js*:

```
document.getElementById("heading").style.color = "blue";
```

*2.js*:

```
document.getElementById("heading").style.color = "red";
```

*Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.17801)* and *Firefox (38.0.1)* always result in the heading being the colour red.

However *Google Chrome (45.0.2412.0 canary 64-bit)* occasionally results in the colour blue. *1.js* is always requested first. This anomaly happens only when the network request for *1.js* completes after *2.js*. When this happens, we can see from the ordered scripting events it is because *2.js* is processed first:

1. Receive response for *2.js*
2. Receive response for *1.js*
3. Receive data for *2.js*
4. Finishing loading *2.js*
5. Receive data for *1.js*
6. Finish loading *1.js*
7. Evaluate script file for *2.js*
8. Evaluate script file for *1.js*

What causes our scripting events for *2.js* to occasionally occur before those for *1.js* in *Google Chrome*? Could it be related to the preceding events such as loading (parsing), rendering or painting?

These are the only 3 Source files being executed, no blackboxed scripts and  *index.html* is being read from the browser, not on a local or remote server.

Comment: `async` - it's literally a race condition. the browser will start loading `1.js`, then immediately start loading `2.js`. SOMETIMES 1.js will return first and get executed, sometimes 2.js will win. There's no way to predict it. it'll be 1,2 for hours/days, then someone's backhoe will sever a fibreoptic line just after the 1.js request goes out, and suddenly 2.js wins the race because it took a newer/faster path.

Comment: This is more or less the definition of async.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, could you elaborate why 1.js always wins the race in Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.17801) and Firefox (38.0.1), but sometimes loses in Google Chrome (45.0.2412.0 canary 64-bit)?

Comment: no idea. why is the dashboard a different color in a chrysler v.s. a ford? they're completely different internally (obviously).

Comment: @Marc B, Precisely, hopefully somebody can elaborate on the internals. For example, if it is due to the HTML Parsing, somebody may have further knowledge on the Blink rendering/layout engine.

Comment: nothing to do with parsing. parsing html just builds a dom tree. it has entirely everything to do with the implementation of the JS engine in the browser, its internal network stack, etc...

Comment: @Marc B, It was an example but thank you, it would be great to know which part of the Chrome Canary open source V8 JS engine implementation causes this rare behaviour not present in IE or Firefox

Comment: if there's an archive of old chrome versions around, install one from the pre-V8 days and see if the behavior persists there...